# google-cloud-dataprep: Importing Excel from GCS bucket gives gibberish characters

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to import an excel spreadsheet from a GCS bucket as a dataset into a flow.
But it's giving me gibberish data in the preview and also when I try to wrangle the data.
The same spreadsheet works fine when I upload from my computer.

Any idea how I can fix the issue when loading form the GCS bucket ?

[image: Gibberish when importing from GCS]

Comment: The gcs bucket  is in the same project as the flow

Comment: Did you try changing the encoding of the file during the import from GCS?

Comment: I tried different encodings like UTF-16, ISO-.... but no luck, is there a particular recommendation ,the default setting is UTF-8

Comment: Yes, can you try windows-1255? =)

Comment: I have tried all the encoding options, but no luck.